# Run R Shiny app in debug mode

Tags: r, debugging, rstudio, shiny

Is it possible to run shiny app in debug mode. i.e: after I issue runApp to launch the (server.R and ui.R) I get the console's R prompt ">" back?
Justification: Debug the application while it is running

Thank you
Mjj

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by setting a breakpoint in your server code. When the app hits this line, it will enter debug mode and you can use the R console.